# MVC Web API AutoFac Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac

In my setup class I have the following code (using Autofac and the MVC Web API Template in Visual Studio)

```
builder.RegisterType<CRMUserStore<IdentityUser>>().As<IUserLoginStore<IdentityUser>>()
    .InstancePerRequest();
```

Then in the Startup.Auth class I have the following

```
UserManagerFactory = () => new UserManager<IdentityUser>(
    DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserLoginStore<IdentityUser>>());
```

This returns null.  Then when I try instead of the above

```
UserManagerFactory = () => new UserManager<IdentityUser>(
    _container.Resolve<IUserLoginStore<IdentityUser>>()); //_container is IContainer
```

I get an error saying

An exception of type 'Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException' occurred in Autofac.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web integration always request dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container itself.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `IUserLoginStore` service is being registered as `InstancePerRequest` which means it can only be resolved from within the context of a request. I.e. a lifetime scope tagged as 'AutofacWebRequest'.

AutoFac automatically creates a new lifetime scope tagged as 'AutofacWebRequest' for each request, and hence services resolved within the request can access this tagged scope.
I would imagine that the `Startup.Auth` class is running at the scope of the MVC application and outside of any specific request. Therefore it doesn't have access to the tagged scope and hence the exception `No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest'`.

If this is the case then changing the `IUserLoginStore` registration to `InstancePerLifetimeScope` will allow it to resolve correctly within the `Startup.Auth` class.

However, this would also change the behaviour when resolving within a request to always getting the application scoped service as well. Without seeing more of your code I can't tell if this would be an issue.

Here's a related question with a nice writeup: [Autofac - InstancePerHttpRequest vs InstancePerLifetimeScope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127000/autofac-instanceperhttprequest-vs-instanceperlifetimescope-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

**Note** - Ensure you have configured Asp.Net MVC to use AutoFac for dependency resolution as described in the AutoFac documentation ( https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MvcIntegration ).

> protected void Application_Start() {
>       var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
>       builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
>       var container = builder.Build();
>       DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
>
> ```
> // Other MVC setup...
> ```

Comment: After I register Autofac when I try DependencyResolver.Current.GetType().ToString() I get
"System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver+DefaultDependencyResolver"  Shouldn't it be Autofac?

Comment: Looks like you are using the default Asp.Net Mvc dependency resolver: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.dependencyresolver(v=vs.118).aspx. You need to register AutoFac with Asp.Net Mvc as follows: https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MvcIntegration