# AzureFunctions.Autofac threadsafe dependency injection issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, azure-functions, autofac

I am using [AzureFunctions.Autofac](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AzureFunctions.Autofac) to inject into my Azure Functions web api. An example of the config:

```cs
  public class DIConfig
    {
        public DIConfig()
        {
            DependencyInjection.Initialize(builder =>
            {
                // DAL
                builder.Register<IDbContext>(c => new SecretCompanyContext()).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
                builder.RegisterType<SecretCompanyContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
                builder.RegisterType<SecretCompanyContext>().As<ICartContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
                builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

                // Services               
                builder.RegisterType<InventoryServices>().As<IInventoryServices>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

                // Controllers ported from ASP.NET MVC Web API
                builder.RegisterType<InventoryController>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            });
        }
```

Then my Azure functions, I have one class that defines all methods in the API

```cs
    [DependencyInjectionConfig(typeof(DIConfig))]
    public class InventoryFunctions : FunctionsApi
    {
        [FunctionName("GetProductsByCategory")]
        // /inventory/categories/{id}/products
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetProductsByCategory(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "inventory/categories/{id}/products")]
            HttpRequestMessage req,
            TraceWriter log,
            int id,
            [Inject] InventoryController controller)
        {
            // do stuff
            var result = await controller.GetProductsByCategory(id);
            return JsonResponse(result, HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }

        [FunctionName("GetInventoryBySku")]
        // /inventory/skus?sku=ASDF&sku=ASDG&sku=ASDH
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetInventoryBySku(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "inventory")]
            HttpRequestMessage req,
            TraceWriter log,
            [Inject] InventoryController controller)
        {
            // do stuff
            var result = await controller.QueryInventoryBySkuList(skuList);
            return JsonResponse(result, HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }

        [FunctionName("UpdateProductsQuantity")]
        // /inventory
        // Post
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UpdateProductsQuantity(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "put", Route = "inventory")]
            HttpRequestMessage req,
            TraceWriter log,
            [Inject] InventoryController controller)
        {
            // do stuff
            var inventoryProducts = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<InvProductOperation>>();
            var result = await controller.UpdateAvailableProductsQuantity(inventoryProducts);
            return JsonResponse(result, HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
```

But I keep getting this error:

> A second operation started on this context before a previous 
>   asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that 
>   any asynchronous operations have completed before calling 
>   another method on this context. Any instance members are not 
>   guaranteed to be thread safe.

I have verified that `async` and `await` are used properly, so following the error message's recommendation isn't fixing it. What appears to be the issue is that `IDbContext` is not honoring the `InstancePerLifetimeScope` as expected. Is this happening because I have more than one method in my `InventoryFunctions` class? Or is AzureFunctions.Autofac not threadsafe?

Comment: Are you using Azure Function v1 or v2 ? v2 has native support to DI.

Comment: @Thomas using native IoC wouldn't change anything. It depends on the scope used for the `DbContext` that is being registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going by this SO answer: [Autofac - InstancePerHttpRequest vs InstancePerLifetimeScope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127000/autofac-instanceperhttprequest-vs-instanceperlifetimescope/23356038#23356038) which said that `InstancePerLifetimeScope` was the non-ASP.NET equivalent of `InstancePerRequest`.

I spoke to the developers and they said the truth is that getting one DbContext per HttpRequest was the default behavior when you simply register using `builder.RegisterType<SecretCompanyContext>.As<IDbContext>()` so there's some misinformation out there.

So the solution is, instead of using

```
builder.Register<IDbContext>(c => new SecretCompanyContext()).InstancePerDependency();
```

or

```
builder.RegisterType<SecretCompanyContext>().As<IDbContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

one should just use

```
builder.RegisterType<SecretCompanyContext>().As<IDbContext>();
```

if the goal is one instance per HTTP request.

Comment: So what's the solution in that?

Comment: @alsami See above.

Answer (score 1):

Change the registration of the DbContext to this:

```cs
 builder.Register<IDbContext>(c => new SecretCompanyContext()).InstancePerDependency();
```

You can find a deeper explanation of mine for why this is happening [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767910/entity-framework-core-a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a-previ/48783504#48783504).

Comment: If that didn't work for you, you must be creating another context within that registration of IDbContext.